# How do I properly align multi-column text file?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk, grep

This is my file:

```
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/1/1         DC  6/1/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/2/1         DC  6/2/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/3/1         DC  6/3/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/4/1         DC  6/4/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/5/1         DC  6/5/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/6/1         DC  6/6/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/7/1         DC  6/7/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/8/1         DC  6/8/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/9/1         DC  6/9/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/10/1         DC  6/10/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/11/1         DC  6/11/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/12/1         DC  6/12/5         0 Y
```

I have alignment problem from the row after digit 10 is started. And I want the format below mentioned,

```
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/1/1         DC  6/1/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/2/1         DC  6/2/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/3/1         DC  6/3/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/4/1         DC  6/4/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/5/1         DC  6/5/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/6/1         DC  6/6/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/7/1         DC  6/7/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/8/1         DC  6/8/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/9/1         DC  6/9/5         0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/10/1        DC  6/10/5        0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/11/1        DC  6/11/5        0 Y
TLRUIDA CBdms    Status            DP  6/12/1        DC  6/12/5        0 Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sed command fixes the given output:

```
sed 's=\(D[CP] *./../.\) =\1=g'
```

It removes one space after the `./../.` after DC and DP. If the other numbers can get longer, too, sed is probably not the right tool for the job.

Comment: yes it is working fine.... thanks @choroba

Answer (score 16):

The right tool for this job is `column`. You can specify column separator with `-o` (on OS X it's `-s`) , e.g.:

```
column -t -o '   ' file
```

gives

```
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/1/1    DC   6/1/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/2/1    DC   6/2/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/3/1    DC   6/3/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/4/1    DC   6/4/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/5/1    DC   6/5/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/6/1    DC   6/6/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/7/1    DC   6/7/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/8/1    DC   6/8/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/9/1    DC   6/9/5    0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/10/1   DC   6/10/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/11/1   DC   6/11/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA   CBdms   Status   DP   6/12/1   DC   6/12/5   0   Y
```

Comment: I am using solaris 10.... column is not working

Comment: @pmaipmui Thats a pitty.

Comment: I am undeleting this since the next person to find the question might not be on a Solaris machine and this would be useful for them.

Comment: 6 years later, this worked for me on linux. Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, it will be enough to just change all occurrences of two or more spaces to a tab:

```
sed 's/  */\t/g' file
```

For a more general solution, you can make sure each column is printed with the right width using `printf`. You can do this directly in the shell:

```
$ while read line; do 
    printf '%-8s%-6s%-7s%-3s%-8s%-3s%-7s%-2s%-2s\n' $line; 
done < file
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/1/1   DC 6/1/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/2/1   DC 6/2/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/3/1   DC 6/3/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/4/1   DC 6/4/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/5/1   DC 6/5/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/6/1   DC 6/6/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/7/1   DC 6/7/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/8/1   DC 6/8/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/9/1   DC 6/9/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/10/1  DC 6/10/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/11/1  DC 6/11/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/12/1  DC 6/12/5 0 Y
```

Or, more safely for arbitrary input:

```
$ while read a b c d e f g h i; do 
    printf '%-8s%-6s%-7s%-3s%-8s%-3s%-7s%-2s%-2s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e" "$f" "$g" "$h" "$i"; 
done < file
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/1/1   DC 6/1/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/2/1   DC 6/2/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/3/1   DC 6/3/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/4/1   DC 6/4/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/5/1   DC 6/5/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/6/1   DC 6/6/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/7/1   DC 6/7/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/8/1   DC 6/8/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/9/1   DC 6/9/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/10/1  DC 6/10/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/11/1  DC 6/11/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/12/1  DC 6/12/5 0 Y
```

You could do it more quickly and succinctly using something like `perl`:

```
$ perl -lane 'printf "%-8s%-6s%-7s%-3s%-8s%-3s%-7s%-2s%-2s\n",@F' file
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/1/1   DC 6/1/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/2/1   DC 6/2/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/3/1   DC 6/3/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/4/1   DC 6/4/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/5/1   DC 6/5/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/6/1   DC 6/6/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/7/1   DC 6/7/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/8/1   DC 6/8/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/9/1   DC 6/9/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/10/1  DC 6/10/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/11/1  DC 6/11/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA CBdms Status DP 6/12/1  DC 6/12/5 0 Y
```

The benefit of using `printf` is that you can specify a minimum column width for each column. The means that if one of your columns can have a much longer value, it will still work. For example, if the first field of one of your lines could be `averylongfieldindeed`, you could set the minimum width of the 1st column to 21 and have aligned output:

```
$ perl -lane 'printf "%-21s%-6s%-7s%-3s%-8s%-3s%-7s%-2s%-2s\n",@F' file
averylongfieldindeed CBdms Status DP 6/1/1   DC 6/1/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/2/1   DC 6/2/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/3/1   DC 6/3/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/4/1   DC 6/4/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/5/1   DC 6/5/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/6/1   DC 6/6/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/7/1   DC 6/7/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/8/1   DC 6/8/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/9/1   DC 6/9/5  0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/10/1  DC 6/10/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/11/1  DC 6/11/5 0 Y 
TLRUIDA              CBdms Status DP 6/12/1  DC 6/12/5 0 Y
```

By contrast, using tabs wouldn't work:

```
$ sed  -e "s/\s\+/\t/g" file
averylongfieldindeed    CBdms   Status  DP  6/1/1   DC  6/1/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/2/1   DC  6/2/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/3/1   DC  6/3/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/4/1   DC  6/4/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/5/1   DC  6/5/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/6/1   DC  6/6/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/7/1   DC  6/7/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/8/1   DC  6/8/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/9/1   DC  6/9/5   0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/10/1  DC  6/10/5  0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/11/1  DC  6/11/5  0   Y
TLRUIDA CBdms   Status  DP  6/12/1  DC  6/12/5  0   Y
```

Comment: thanks ...but u just notice one thing... my output format will remain same... i mean the gaps in between words..... if there are 8spaces between two words then it will remain same. but ypur answer changes the format of the output

Comment: @pmaipmui it depends on what you want. You can't have it both ways. If you always want exactly 8 spaces between the columns, then the columns cannot be aligned if they can have different widths. The reason you have the alignment problem is precisely because you always have 8 spaces. You can't both always have 8 spaces and fic the alignment. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want nice columns in the terminal output, you should not use spaces but characters called "TAB". An sed oneliner that replaces all your spaces with TABs is the following

```
sed -i -e "s/\s\+/\t/g" your_input_file
```

Comment: you command is not working

Comment: Eek! The bug is fixed now. I should test even the simplest oneliner before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

we have very simple command for that:

```
tr -s ' ' <input-file >output-file
```

`-s` option removes the occurrence of `<space>` (or any character following it on command line for that matter)